# HotKeys / Macros

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse

I have looked at many forums trying to find a solution to what I need, and have given up and decided to make my own post here.
I want a macro program with these specifications or at least as close as it gets:
Has a GUI,
Can pickup these **STUPID** buttons on the side of my mouse,
Can record mouse movements and keyboard actions/events (hopefully at the same time)
User friendly,
Installed easily preferably via the package manager (3rd party repositories are fine with me).
I do realize what im looking for is somewhat specific and i'm not suprised if there is no application that fits my needs out there.

I've already tried gnee and actiona because they are gui and i had hope (that was crushed) for them

ps

I am not trying to make it type stuff in for me, I am a gamer who wants to hook up those mouse buttons to a game that doesnt detect them.

pss

it is hard to write exactly what i want just in text so talking in some form of voice chat would be nice but thats last resort i guess lol

EDIT: I have just thought of mapping these keys to a new virtual key (not sure where i am going with this, but ill do some research on it)

Comment: I don't want to make a new post so i'll just continue this since its related -
Is it possible to make new "virtual keys" that i can map my mouse buttons to?

Comment: Please only [edit] your question. Don't provide additional material via comments.